# display menu bar on displayed file content in jsp

Tags: css, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, pdf

I am displaying PDF file in a jsp page. I want to display menu bar at the top on the same page. I have written code to display menu bar as well as to display PDF file. But the menu bar is not visible on the page. Menu bar is covered up the PDF file. How to make menu bar visible? Please help. Thank you.

```
     <style>
body
{
background:url('C:\\Users\\workspace3\\elearning\\openbook.jpg') no-repeat     center center fixed;
background-size: cover;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
div ul ul {
display: none;
}
div ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
        }
div ul {
background: #7c0c0c; 
 font-size: 16px;
font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
text-shadow: 3px 2px 3px #333333;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
}
div ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}
div ul li {
float: left;
}
div ul li:hover {
    background: #ebd3d3;
}
    div ul li:hover a {
        color: #4f9dd5;
    }
div ul li a {
    display: block; padding: 25px 30px;
    color:#ebd3d3; text-decoration: none;
}
div ul ul {
background:#7c0c0c; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
div ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #4f9dd5;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4f9dd5;
    position: relative;
}
    div ul ul li a {
        padding: 15px 40px;
        color: #ebd3d3;
    }
</style>
<body>
<div>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.jsp"><span>Content</span></a>
<ul>
<li><a href="Cont.jsp"><span>Text Content</span></a></li>
<li><a href="Video.jsp"><span>Video</span></a></li>
<li><a href="Ppt.jsp"><span>PPT</span></a></li>
</ul></li>
<li><a href="Test1.jsp"><span>Quiz</span></a></li>
<li><a href="Forum5.jsp"><span>Assignment</span></a>
<ul>
<li><a href="Download2.jsp"><span>Assignment Questions</span></a></li>
<li><a href="Upload1.jsp"><span>Upload Assignment</span></a></li>
</ul></li>
<li> <a href="Forum1.jsp"><span>Forum</span></a></li>
<li> <a href="logout.jsp"><span>Logout</span></a></li>
</font></ul></div>
<%
File temp=new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\content\\o.pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachement;       filename=\""+temp+"\"");
InputStream isStream = null;
ServletOutputStream sosStream = null;
try
{
response.flushBuffer();
isStream =new FileInputStream(temp);
sosStream =response.getOutputStream();
int ibit = 250;
while ((ibit) >= 0)
{
ibit = isStream.read();
sosStream.write(ibit)
}
}catch (IOException e)
{
out.println(e);
}
sosStream.flush();
sosStream.close();
isStream.close();%>
</body>
</html>
```